# Fetch data from the backend, then pass the data to editorState using draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm creating a component that will display the data from backend by using draft-js. The data from the backend also is being stored using draft-js. The data is not being display and also there's no error message.

Sample Data from the backend is being parse before passing to the viewContent.js

Hello World

I tried to create a variable to check if the code is working. I tried this approach const sample = `<p>Hello World`. This one is working if pass this on contenBlocks.

viewContent.js

```
import {
  EditorState,
  ContentState,
  convertFromHTML,
} from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

const viewContent = ({ content }) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState();

  const clearState = () => {
    ContentState.createFromText('');
  };

  const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    let currentContentAsHTML = JSON.stringify(
      draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    );
    convertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const contentBlocks = convertFromHTML(content);

    const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      contentBlocks.contentBlocks,
      contentBlocks.entityMap
    );

    setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
  }, [content]);

  return (
    <div className='comment-container p-2 border rounded-md'>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        wrapperClassName='wrapper-class'
        editorClassName='editor-class'
        toolbarClassName='toolbar-class'
        onClick={clearState}
      />
    </div>
  );


};

export default viewContent;
```

Parent Compontent

```
<viewContent
                      content={taskInfo.taskNote}
                      convertedContent={(convertedContent) =>
                        setTaskInfo((prevState) => ({
                          ...prevState,
                          taskNote: convertedContent,
                        }))
                      }
                    />
```

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set editor state after `ViewContent` component rendered completely. update your component as below:

```js
...

useEffect(() => {
  const contentBlocks = convertFromHTML(content);

  const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    contentBlocks.contentBlocks,
    contentBlocks.entityMap
  );

  setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
}, [content]);

...
```

Comment: Thank sir, question do you encounter this behavior when I click the edit it adding a new line tag inside the editor

Comment: Your welcome and no I didn't encounter this issue before. maybe sharing your implementation is helpful for resolve it!

Comment: I think the problem is when I'm trying to pass the onChange value to the parent component. Also update the code above

Comment: If reproduce this issue in an environment like codesandbox I can work on it because in the codes I can't find any problem